# How to transfer data between databases with SELECT statement in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

So I am stuck on this Teradata problem and I am looking to the community for advice as I am new to the TD platform. I am currently working with a Teradata Data Warehouse and have an interesting task to solve. Currently we store our information in a live production database but want to stage tables in another database before using FastExport to export the files. Basically we want to move our tables into a database to take a quick snapshot.

I have been exploring different solutions and am unsure how to proceed. I need to be able to automate a create table process from one DB in Teradata to another. The tricky part is I would like to create many tables off of the source table using a WHERE clause. For example, I have a transaction table and want to take a snapshot of the transaction table for a certain date range month by month. Meaning that the original table Transaction would be split into many tables such as Transaction_May2001, Transaction_June2001, Transaction_July2001 and so on and so forth.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to any of the client utilities that get distributed with the DBS? TPT is a specialized utility that can move data between two systems utilizing FastExport/FastLoad protocols.

Comment: My advice is to stop what you are doing.  It's a bad idea.  It's neither normalized nor does it have a star schema.  It will make querying very difficult.

Comment: @ryanbwork Ryan, I do have access to TTU which includes TPT. Is there a sample script that you could provide to give better insight in how TPT work? This was the original idea I started with but got stuck due to lack of material for this specific scenario.

Comment: @JeffreDodd what version do you have? Can you update your SO account to include your e-mail address and I'll send over an example script.

Comment: @Ryanbwork Not sure why my email is not public as it shows. I setup a melt mail address for the next 24 hours. 7FI8uR7anpxd@meltmail.com. Thanks for the script!

Comment: @JeffreDodd check your inbox!

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming by two databases you are referring to the same physical installation of Teradata.

You can use the `CREATE TABLE AS` construct to accomplish this:

```
CREATE TABLE {MyDB}.Transaction_May2001
AS (
SELECT *
FROM Transaction
WHERE Transaction_Date BETWEEN DATE '2001-05-01' AND '2001-05-31'
)
{UNIQUE} PRIMARY INDEX ({Same PI definition as Transaction Table}) 
WITH DATA AND STATS;
```

If you neglect to specify the explicit PI in the CREATE TABLE AS then Teradata will take the first column of the SELECT clause and use it as the PI of the new table.

Otherwise, you would be looking to use a Teradata utility as suggested by ryanbwork in the comment to your question.

Comment: The last two lines have to be switched: WITH DATA AND STATS {UNIQUE} PRIMARY INDEX ({Same PI definition as Transaction Table});